# Facebook oauth display=wap for old cellphones

Tags: facebook

Facebook [roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) states that on July 1st 2012 "The wap dialog display mode will be removed.".
I have taken a look at [dialogs overview](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) and available display methods are page, popup, iframe, or touch. None of them are good for wap usage for older cellphones (no touch support).

The question is how to make wap visitors see wap version of auth dialog on Facebook?

Comment: Thanks Eugen, this question is still an issue over here